# The following partitions are going to be formatted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm trying to install ubuntu on a USB stick identified as /dev/sdb. I went through the process of installation and in the end I got the following message:

> The following partitions are going to be formatted:
>   partition #3 of SCSI1(0,0,0)(sda) as swap
>   partition #1 of SCSI4(0,0,0)(sdb) as ESP
>   partition #2 of SCSI4(0,0,0)(sdb) as ext4

My question is: Why is partition #3 involved? It seems to belong to sda, which is my main internal drive, but I am trying to install on sdb.

Comment: It auto finds any existing swap. You can in selecting partitions select swap and say do not use. And then it only creates a swap file.  Post back if it actually uses sdb's ESP. I never reformat it, but try to use it, but it always has used ESP on sda. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 & 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1229488

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand how I can select swap space and say do not use. Anyway, after it is formatted, will it still be in linux-swap filesystem?

Comment: You only get the choice with Something Else install option. Yes, but if you have other installs using swap the reformat changes UUID & you have to change other installs fstab to get it to boot again. I have a swap on both sda & sdb. If I do not say to not use, it adds both to fstab. If I say do not use for both, now with newer versions it creates a swap file. On one test install I commented out the swaps in fstab and added a swap file, but that required a lot of steps.